# Postscripts – before or after the signature?

Tags: greetings, email, correspondence

When I write an email, I sometimes want to add some postscripts, but I don't know where to put it? Shall I put it before my signature or after that?

> Dear Mr. Felani,
>
> Blah Blah Blah.
>
> **P.S: Some Other Blah**
>
> Regards,
>   Ashkan

Or something like this:

> Dear Mr. Felani,
>
> Blah Blah Blah.
>
> Regards,
>   Ashkan
>
> **P.S: Some Other Blah**

Comment: I think the second one is more formally correct, but I've used both forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A postscript originated from *postscriptum*(Latin) meaning *post*(after) +scriptum*, the past participle of *scribere*(to write). It is an additional remark at the end of the letter **after the signature** introduced by P.S.

Comment: Just a little addition: Because it is _post_, there's no reason to include it before the signature. If you have something to say before you close your letter with your signature, just say it. You don't need to add the P.S. since it won't actually be _post_ anything.

Answer (score 5):

A postscript is a passage at the end of a letter, following the signature. It only makes sense in the context of a letter composed by hand or on a typewriter, to accommodate an afterthought when you have already finished your letter, and don't want to retype or rewrite the whole letter again.

Answer (score 0):

Although apparently the use of P.S no longer makes sense nowadays, it can also be used for aesthetic purposes or simply to emphasize part of the message.

> The P.S. is the most charming part of a letter. It’s the wink you give as you walk away.

```
—Shaun Usher, author of Letters of Note, for The Wall Street Journal
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asks where a PS should be placed.